# Importing extern javascript (clamp.js) for line clamping not working

Tags: javascript, css, ellipsis

I want to clamp long texts with Clamp.js (https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js) but it is not working.

I only know a bit of JavaScript so there is probably some trivial misconception.

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js/blob/master/clamp.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: aqua">
        <p id="test">super long text</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        var paragraph = document.getElementById("test");
        $clamp(paragraph, { clamp: 3 });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

expected: three lines of text + ellipsis

result: nothing

Comment: Hi mate, try not to reference file from github directly. In your case it just downloads an empty file, that why it is not working for you. Use CDN solutions if you don't want to setup a build tool. GL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Clamp.js/0.5.1/clamp.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

The only thing that I've change and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're using $clamp but not actually setting the value, I've never used the Clamp before, but it'll either be:

```
<script>
     $clamp(document.getElementById("test"), { clamp: 3 });
</script>
```

or (likely this one)

```
<script>
    var paragraph = document.getElementById("test");
     $clamp(paragraph, { clamp: 3 });
     document.getElementById("test").value = paragraph;
 </script>
```